# what type of observable UniRx CombineLatest() operator returns ? cold or hot?

Tags: unity-game-engine, observable, reactive-programming, system.reactive, unirx

i'm using UniRx to use streams in unity. im using the CombineLatest() operator to combine two subjects and publish this value in one of the streams. when i'm using the generated value outside the .Subscribe() the OnNext() is called and works perfectly:

```
Observable.CombineLatest(positionStream, speed, (position, speed) =>
        {
            return position + speed;
        }).TakeLast(1).Subscribe(a =>
          {
              last_value = a;
          });
        positionStream.OnNext(last_value);
```

but when i'm calling the OnNext() inside the .Subscribe() the .OnNext() is never called:

```
Observable.CombineLatest(positionStream, speed, (position, speed) =>
    {
        return position + speed;
    }).TakeLast(1).Subscribe(a =>
      {
          positionStream.OnNext(a);
      });
```

can someone please tell me what's wrong with the second approach? i'm suspecting that CombineLatest() returns cold observable and that's why second approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `.TakeLast(1)` which requires that the source observable does two things. (1) produces a value and (2) completes. Your code doesn't show how your `CombineLatest` completes so it will appear as if no value is produced.

Here's a version of your code that does call the subscription:

```
var positionStream = new Subject<int>();
var speed = new Subject<int>();

Observable
    .CombineLatest(positionStream, speed, (position, speed) => position + speed)
    .TakeLast(1)
    .Subscribe(a =>
    {
        positionStream.OnNext(a);
        Console.WriteLine("!");
    });

speed.OnNext(42);
positionStream.OnNext(42);

speed.OnNext(42);
positionStream.OnNext(42);

speed.OnCompleted();
positionStream.OnCompleted();
```

Note that it only calls the subscription once.

Now, if I understand what you're trying to do, it seems you want to be able to manually reset a position, but also send thru speed values which also update the current position.

If that's right, try this:

```
var positionStream = new Subject<int>();
var speed = new Subject<int>();

var final_position =
    positionStream
        .Select(p => speed.Scan(p, (a, x) => a + x).StartWith(p))
        .Switch();

final_position
    .Subscribe(a => Console.WriteLine(a));

positionStream.OnNext(42);
speed.OnNext(2);
speed.OnNext(5);
positionStream.OnNext(16);
speed.OnNext(4);
```

That produces the following values:

```
42
44
49
16
20
```

---

Here's how to push all the values into `positionStream`:

```
var final_position =
    positionStream
        .Select(p =>
            speed
                .Scan(p, (a, x) => a + x)
                .Do(y => positionStream.OnNext(y))
                .StartWith(p))
        .Switch();
```

I don't like the use of `Do` to force side-effects, but it works here.

Comment: thanks for your response, i wanted to publish the new calculated position in the same positionStream i had. is there anyway to do so without defining a new stream (in this code final_position) and subscribing to it?

Answer (score -1):

You are calling `OnNext` while the Subject is in the middle hand handling the previous on next call. This would cause a stack overflow.

If you want to update an object's position every time unit, then you should set up an `Interval`.